# how to show list of properties and methods of a class reference in xcode4?

Tags: xcode4, xcode3to4

In xcode3, list of properties and methods of a reference where displayed in a frame.
Can we do the same thing in xcode4?

Answer (score 0):

Try esc on the code editor, the avable methods appearing.
If you want to see the documentation: press alt + click on the object